# Add alias record in aws?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm getting access denied when i'm adding alias record through java using amazon IAM credentials.

My policy for user is as below...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/<hostedzoneid>"

            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::change/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Java code:

```
try{
            ChangeBatch changeBatch = new ChangeBatch();
            Collection<Change> changes = new ArrayList<Change>();
            Change change = new Change();
            change.setAction(ChangeAction.CREATE);
            changes.add(change);
            changeBatch.setChanges(changes);

            ResourceRecordSet resourceRecordSet = new ResourceRecordSet();
                AliasTarget alias=new AliasTarget();
                alias.setHostedZoneId(hostedZoneId);
                alias.setDNSName(ip);
                alias.setEvaluateTargetHealth(false);
                resourceRecordSet.setAliasTarget(alias);

            resourceRecordSet.setName(recordSetName);
            resourceRecordSet.setType(recordSetType);

            change.setResourceRecordSet(resourceRecordSet);

            ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest changeResourceRecordSetsRequest = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest();
            changeResourceRecordSetsRequest.setHostedZoneId(hostedZoneId);
            changeResourceRecordSetsRequest.setChangeBatch(changeBatch);

            AmazonRoute53Client route53client = new AmazonRoute53Client(connection.getCredentials(), connection.getClientConfiguration());
//Facing error in return sattement
            return route53client.changeResourceRecordSets(changeResourceRecordSetsRequest);
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
           }
```

Error i'm facing is:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:iam::564371343498020:user/tester is not authorized to access this resource (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: e05f85d9-40ab-11e5-9914-9512262733a4)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1078)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:461)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:296)
    at com.amazonaws.services.route53.AmazonRoute53Client.invoke(AmazonRoute53Client.java:2358)
    at com.amazonaws.services.route53.AmazonRoute53Client.changeResourceRecordSets(AmazonRoute53Client.java:2029)
    at in.ss.util.AmazonWS.createResourceRecords(AmazonWS.java:64)
...
```

Am I missing any resource or action line?.Please help me

Comment: Can you provide more information about the code that is failing and the exact error returned? You could test the permissions by using the AWS CLI to make the call using the same credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the edit John, any solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to successfully run the following AWS CLI command using your security policy:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --profile stack --hosted-zone-id Z3NAOXXXXXI1HM --change-batch '{ 
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "CREATE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "foo.bar.com",
        "Type": "CNAME",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "foo.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

The only change I made to the policy was to use my hosted-zone-id (as shown above, but obfuscated here).

Comment: I'm getting problem in creating alias record with type 'A' .....the above policy is working fine with normal record with type 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

"com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:iam::564371343498020:user/tester is not authorized to access this resource ("

This is your problem. You do not have permission to do this kinda actions.
Ask your aws administrator to give your account permission.